# How to Synchronously Get InnerText From ASP.NET Core Tag Helper

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I see plenty of examples using ASP.NET Core Tag Helpers of using ProcessAsync to get the InnerText of an HTML element. For example, the following works as expected:

```
    public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context,
                              TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        var childContent = await output.GetChildContentAsync();
        var innerHtml = childContent.GetContent();
        output.Content.SetHtmlContent("---" + innerHtml + "---"); 
    }
```

However, I want to get it synchronously and the following does not. How can I get the innertext with Process (sync)?

```
    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        var innerHtml = output.Content.GetContent();
        output.Content.SetHtmlContent("---" + innerHtml + "---");
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why? What difference does it make to your situation? What are you doing that you think requires synchronous access?

If you believe you do need it then

```
var innerHtml = output.GetChildContentAsync().Result.GetContent();
```

Comment: Thanks @blowdart .  My understanding (from the asp.net team) is that if you don't need async (like you are just doing some simple string concat work, async is not only not necesary but ads overhead.

Comment: Not at that point. Razor is async. You're already async. It should make no difference.

Comment: that makes sense.  Thanks for explaining.